# Can I run create-react-app or create-next-app from a node file/api endpoint?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, command-line, node-modules

I am trying to create a node file at an API endpoint which when called upon will run create-react-app and generate another react app in a sibling directory. Right now I have the express server and endpoint all setup however when I make a call to the endpoint all i get is the file directory and a basic package.json - no real execution of create-react-app. Please see controller code below.

```
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const createReactApp = (appName) => {
  try {
    // Step 1: Create the app using create-react-app
    console.log('Creating a new React app...');
    const appPath = path.join(process.cwd(), appName);
    execSync(`npx create-react-app ${appName}`, { stdio: 'inherit', cwd: process.cwd() });

    // Step 2: Move the generated app folder to the correct path
    const appFolderName = `${appName}-app`;
    const newPath = path.join(process.cwd(), appFolderName);
    fs.renameSync(appPath, newPath);

    // Step 3: Move into the app's folder
    process.chdir(newPath);

    // Step 4: Update the package.json scripts to include a custom start command
    const packageJsonPath = path.join(newPath, 'package.json');
    const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(packageJsonPath, 'utf8'));
    packageJson.scripts.start = 'react-scripts start';
    fs.writeFileSync(packageJsonPath, JSON.stringify(packageJson, null, 2));

    console.log('React app setup completed.');
    console.log(`To start the app, run "cd ${appFolderName}" and then "npm start".`);

    return { success: true, message: 'React app created successfully' };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating React app:', error.message);
    return { success: false, message: 'Error creating React app' };
  }
};


module.exports = { createReactApp };
```

I am running this through postman to create a react app locally but all that is returned is the name of the app and an empty package.json file. In postman I get an error socket hangup but of course I am expecting a boilerplate react app in the named directory. Please see package.json -

```
{
  "name": "my-react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true
}
```